# File is not closing properly

Tags: python, file, python-2.7

I'm not sure why, but the file 'refined.txt' is not closing properly (see code below). I get a Windows error ("The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process") when I try to rename the file in the last line of code.

It is important that this file is renamed because this piece of code is part of a for loop, so if I don't rename the file to something unique it will get written over.

I am hoping that someone will be able to tell me why the file isn't closing properly.

Code:

```
    of = open('refined.txt')
    d=of.readlines()

    for line in d[:20]:
        #some code

    of.close()    
    os.rename('refined.txt', new)
```

Comment: Could you open the file with a unique name, rather than open it with the hardcoded name and rename it after?

Comment: Can you rename it before opening it instead?

Comment: @JohnZwinck unfortunately I need to extract info from the txt file and include it in the file name, that is why I renamed it after.

Comment: Well if you really get stuck you could simply write the contents (which you have already read) into the new filename.  But hopefully it doesn't come to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `with` statement to open the file instead, and see if that makes any difference.

```
with open('refined.txt') as of:
    d = of.readlines()

for line in d[:20]:
    #some code

os.rename('refined.txt', new)
```

Comment: `with` is the preferred way of doing it as it will always clean up and close the file. no chance of you forgetting to close

Comment: No problem. [See more info on the 'with' statement in the official Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)